# How to set Vertical Alignment for a text using Xceed Richtextbox

Tags: wpf, xaml

Here is my sample code:

```
<xctk:RichTextBox Height="100" x:Name="rchTextBox" Text="Testing"
                  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"/>
```

namespace used:

```
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

But these property shows no effect.
[Here is the screenshot for the above code changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNbNG.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried using styles or override the existing one?

Comment: Yes, tried that too.

Comment: Then don't use xceed,..